# Adding Logic for an Optional Argument in a Custom HL7 Parsing Function

Tags: vba, excel, function, parsing, hl7

I wrote a custom function that parses an HL7 interface message.  These are messages sent between healthcare information systems, but basically it's just a long text string, delimited with various characters to indicate different fields, that I paste into a cell in Excel.  The function I created searches and counts to find the fields specified in the arguments.

DISCLAIMER: I am new to VBA.  I've been teaching myself via online research and trial-and-error over the past 3-4 weeks, so I'm no VBA expert.  I'd prefer NOT to use arrays because when I tried that, the code got too complex for me to troubleshoot.  So, I'm OK with the code being easy-to-follow, as opposed to being the fastest/most-efficient.

Anyhow, I've got it working pretty well to do what I want, but I'm stuck on adding in logic for an OPTIONAL argument.

So, this is how I WANT it to work:

Formula `=KWHL7(A1, "MSH", 8)`

NOTE only 3 arguments

Result I Want `ADT^A08`

Result I Get `ADT`

NOTE I know I told it to stop at the next instance of "HL7_SUBFIELD_DELIMITER" which is " ^ "

Formula `=KWHL7(A1, "MSH", 8,1)`

NOTE the optional 4th argument

Result I Want  `ADT`

Formula `=KWHL7(A1, "MSH", 8,2)`

NOTE the optional 4th argument

Result I Want `A08`

The contents "value" of cell A1:

```
<11>MSH|^~\&|OPS|384|RISIC|384|20160923093012||ADT^A08|Q1230569238T1410271390|P|2.3|||*PM_ALLERGY*|||8859/1<13>
EVN||20160923<13>
PID|1||000000808^^^SCH MRN^MRN^SC||ZZTEST^LEANN||20160706|F|||459 CORPORATION ST.^^BEAVER^PA^15009^USA||(724)775-7418^PRN|||S||000000008082^^^SCH Account Number^FIN NBR|||||||0<13>
PV1|1|I|SCH Periop^^^^^^||||08888^Bullian^Leann~08888^Naylor^Daniel|||10|||||||08888^Nguyen-potter^Rose~00187^TEST^STCHRISRES^L^MD^^MD^^SCH Doc Number|1|1287593^^^TEMP FIN^VISITID||||||||||||||||||||384||A|||20160707131900<13>
PV2|||PA^<13>
OBX|1||Dosing Weight^WEIGHT||5|kg<13>
OBX|2||Height^HEIGHT||25|cm<13>
AL1|1|Drug|d00308^morphine^Multum Drug||66382015<13>
ZAL|||16655315|16655315||Active|66382015^Anaphylaxis^673967||||20160923093008|^Naylor^Daniel|0<13>
AL1|3|Drug|d00012^codeine^Multum Drug||103576018<13>
ZAL|||16655323|16655307||Active|103576018^Diarrhea^673967||||20160923093008|^Naylor^Daniel|0<13>
<28><13>
```

My VBA code (sorry for all the comments, I'm just learning!):

```
Public Function KWHL7(KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message As Variant, KW_HL7_Segment_Name As String, KW_HL7_Field_Number As Integer)

                    'KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message = KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message.Value
                    'KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message = ActiveCell.Value
                    'KW_HL7_Segment_Name = "PID"
                    'KW_HL7_Field_Number = 18

        Const HL7_SEGMENT_DELIMITER = vbLf  'using "<13>" did not work due to carriage return
        Const HL7_FIELD_DELIMITER = "|" ' Pipe means next field
        Const HL7_SUBFIELD_DELIMITER = "^"
            'Various carriage returns and line breaks: vbLf, vbCr, vbCrLf, vbNewLine, Chr(10), Chr(13)

        KWSegmentStringToSearchFor = HL7_SEGMENT_DELIMITER & KW_HL7_Segment_Name  'Using the segment delimiter ("<13>" or "vbLf" / carriage return) before segment name implies that the segment / line STARTS with this text

        KWSegmentCharacterPosition = InStr(1, KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, KWSegmentStringToSearchFor)
        '** FOR TESTING ** MsgBox ("Segment Character Position: " & KWSegmentCharacterPosition & ", 5 Characters starting there = " & Mid(KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, KWSegmentCharacterPosition, 5))

        'Now we have the character position of the start of the proper SEGMENT / line
        'Now we have to find the Proper Field in that segment
        'So we'll use this position + the length of the end of the Segment Delimiter as the start
        '***WARNING***: Still must add logic to make sure we stop if we encounter another Segment Delimiter

        KWFieldCharacterPosition = KWSegmentCharacterPosition + Len(HL7_SEGMENT_DELIMITER)  'instead of starting at character 0, start at the beginning of the segment found previously
        ' ** FOR TESTING ** MsgBox ("Length of Segment Delimiter = " & Len(HL7_SEGMENT_DELIMITER))
        ' ** FOR TESTING ** MsgBox ("Field Character Position: " & KWFieldCharacterPosition & ", 5 Characters starting there = " & Mid(KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, KWFieldCharacterPosition, 5))

        For J = 1 To KW_HL7_Field_Number
        KWFieldCharacterPosition = InStr(KWFieldCharacterPosition + 1, KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, HL7_FIELD_DELIMITER)
        If KWFieldCharacterPosition = 0 Then Exit For
        Next

        ' ** FOR TESTING ** MsgBox ("Field Character Position: " & KWFieldCharacterPosition & ", 5 Characters starting there = " & Mid(KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, KWFieldCharacterPosition, 5))

        'Determine the number of characters to return after the start position
        'Want to pull text UNTIL the next Segment Delimiter or Field Delimiter or Subfield Delimiter

        'Find the position of the next Segment Delimiter or Field Delimiter or Subfield Delimiter
        'Since the InStr function does not accept multiple substrings to search for, and does not allow OR statements inside...
        Next_HL7_Segment_Delimiter = InStr(KWFieldCharacterPosition + 1, KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, HL7_SEGMENT_DELIMITER)
        Next_HL7_Field_Delimiter = InStr(KWFieldCharacterPosition + 1, KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, HL7_FIELD_DELIMITER)
        Next_HL7_Subfield_Delimiter = InStr(KWFieldCharacterPosition + 1, KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, HL7_SUBFIELD_DELIMITER)

        'Added logic to handle issue where the next delimiter was not found, making result 0, making it the lowest value in the next lines of code
        If Next_HL7_Segment_Delimiter = 0 Then Next_HL7_Segment_Delimiter = 99999
        If Next_HL7_Field_Delimiter = 0 Then Next_HL7_Field_Delimiter = 99999
        If Next_HL7_Subfield_Delimiter = 0 Then Next_HL7_Subfield_Delimiter = 99999

        'Set the Last Character Position to whichever Next Delimiter is the lowest / minimum number - Segment or Field or Subfield
        KWLastCharacterPosition = WorksheetFunction.Min(Next_HL7_Segment_Delimiter, Next_HL7_Field_Delimiter, Next_HL7_Subfield_Delimiter)
        ' ** FOR TESTING ** MsgBox ("Last Character Position: " & KWLastCharacterPosition & ", 5 Characters starting there = " & Mid(KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, KWLastCharacterPosition, 5))

        'Determine the number of characters to return in the MID function by subtracting the first character position from the last character position
        KWNumberOfCharactersToReturn = KWLastCharacterPosition - KWFieldCharacterPosition - 1
        ' ** FOR TESTING ** MsgBox ("Number of characters to return: " & KWNumberOfCharactersToReturn)

        KWResult = Mid(KW_Cell_With_HL7_Message, KWFieldCharacterPosition + 1, KWNumberOfCharactersToReturn)
                    'MsgBox ("Result: Segment " & KW_HL7_Segment_Name & ":" & KW_HL7_Field_Number & " is " & KWResult)
                    KWHL7 = KWResult
End Function
```

The problem I had with using the split function was that it put everything into arrays. And since I needed to search FIRST for the KWSegmentStringToSearchFor (i.e. "MSH" or "PV1"), before couting the pipe (|) characters, I would need the array to have separate nested arrays and it got way too confusing for me.

So I abandoned the split function, and my initial plans to use arrays, and just wrote everything to find things sequentially.  So it searches for the KWSegmentStringToSearchFor (i.e. "MSH" or "PV1") with InStr() and then counts the pipe (|) characters from there to determine which number field to return.

Since the strings are of variable length, but delimited with special characters, next I have to determine how many characters to return with the MID function.  So I search for the next delimiter FROM THERE / using the field I found as the starting point and call that the end of my field.

The issue:
The logic considers ANY of the 3 possible delimiters the end of the field.
If I take that out, the code wouldn't know where the end of the string is.

Even if I add some sort of IF statement that IF the optional 4th argument exists (which I'm not sure how to do yet), THEN ignore the ^ as a delimiter... that would always return the full field (ADT^A08).  It wouldn't return just the sub-field / component I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer, would be to split on the LineFeed then it may need tweaking would be, `split(range("a1").value,"|")(intFieldNumber)`
i.e. 
`split("11>MSH|^~\&|OPS|384|RISIC|384|20160923093012||ADT^A08|Q1230569238T1410271390","|")(8)`

gives the result ADT^A08